# image change on location change

Tags: android, image, gps

So I'm trying to make an imageview change its image after the user enters a given GPS location but my app keeps shutting down as soon as I reach this location, I can make a TextView change change its text and so I figured it would be somewhat the same for an image but apparently its not LOL.

I put this in my `public class activity: ImageView sprite;`

I have this just after `setContentView: sprite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`

I'm using an "IF" statement for every location like this:

```
  if(pLat >= homeLat - 0.0001000 && pLat <= homeLat + 0.0001000 
&& pLong >= homeLong - 000.0002000 &&  pLong <=     homeLong + 000.0002000)
    {

    gateway.setText(R.string.home);
    gatewayDis.setText(R.string.homeD);
                       sprite.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minimap));
            // the image change is the only part that isn't working 
}
```

any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change below line from your code

```
sprite.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minimap));
```

to

```
sprite.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minimap));
```

Comment: ok thank you, it was other dudes answer that worked this time, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**sprite.setImageResource(R.drawable.minimap);**

Comment: ok thank you both, it was the second one that worked for me though